# Zip не работает в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Народ хочу создать архив всего диска. Пишу

```
zip -r myarchive.zip *
```

Оно мне выбивает, вот такую ерунду и ничего не пишет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Точнее пишет, но не понятно что ))

В чем может быть причина, и какие еще есть простые способы чтобы создать архив всего диска? Спасибо.

Comment: *Access Denied*, картинку не посмотреть (

Comment: Поправил картинку.

Comment: Не потому ли, что сам себя архивирует?

Comment: А это как? и как этого избежать? )

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно сархивировать диск, то удобнее архивировать именно носитель, а не файловую систему, в которой присутствуют так же и псевдо-файлы - файлы устройств и т.п.

Воспользуйтесь командой `mount`, чтобы посмотреть список смонтированных томов. Например, `/dev/sda1` смонтирован как `/home`. Чтобы его сархивировать, используйте команды:

```
cd /tmp
sudo mkdir sda1
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /tmp/sda1
sudo tar czf sda1_archive.tar.gz /tmp/sda1/
sudo umount /tmp/sda1
sudo rmdir sda1
```